# Vector norm of $\mathbb R^n$, why is $p$-norm$\leq q$-norm if $p\geq q$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Considering 
$$\infty\geq p\geq q\geq1$$

How can I show that the $p$-norm is smaller or equal to the $q$-norm?

I can only show the case for $p=1, q=2$, but have no idea how to show others. 
Thank you!

For $p=1$, $q=2$, 
Take square on 1-norm and 2-norm, 
then $(x_1+x_2+n_3+...+x_n)^2 \geq (x_1^2+x_1^2+...+x_n^2)$ 
So I can have the conclusion for this particular case.

Comment: Can you show us what you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Let $x=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ be a non nul vector. Let $\alpha  = \frac{1}{\|x\|_q}$, then $0\le \alpha |x_i|\le 1$ for all $i$. Thus $(\alpha |x_i|)^p \le (\alpha |x_i|)^q$, hence, using norm homogeneity:
$$\sum_i (\alpha |x_i|)^p \le \sum_i(\alpha |x_i|)^q \le\alpha^q \sum_i( |x_i|)^q  \le 1\,,$$
so:
$$(\sum_i (\alpha |x_i|)^p)^{1/p} \le \alpha \|x\|_p  \le 1\,,$$
and balancing the last inequality,
$$  \|x\|_p  \le \frac{1}{\alpha} \le  \|x\|_q\,.$$

If $x$ is the nul vector, the inequality is trivial.