# Dual proofs of $\lVert f\rVert_q \leq c\lVert f\rVert_p$ and $\lVert f\rVert_p \leq C\lVert f\rVert_q$

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, normed-spaces, topological-vector-spaces

If $(X,\mu)$ is a measure space, $0<p<q<\infty$ (or maybe we can even allow $0\leq p<q\leq \infty$?) and $\mu$ is bounded above, say $\mu(E)\leq M$ for all measurable $E\subseteq X,$ then we get

$$\lVert f\rVert_p\leq M^{\frac{1}{p}-\frac{1}{q}}\lVert f\rVert_q.$$

This may be proved via [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality), such as is done by Daniel Fischer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1397971/16490), or by [Hölder's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality) as is done by Zhanxiong [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1371519/16490).

If the measure is bounded below, $\mu(E)\geq m$ for all measurable $E\subseteq X,$ we have instead

$$m^{\frac{1}{p}-\frac{1}{q}}\lVert f\rVert_q\leq \lVert f\rVert_p.$$

The only proof I've found of this is a little messier, realizing that you can scale the components of a simple function to be less than one, and then raise the components to the power $p/q$ to get a smaller value, and use that and the bound on the measure to relate the norms of the simple functions.

Versions of this proof can be seen around, for example the finite dim proof by Laurent Duval [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1764627/16490), or versions with counting measure by 1015 [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/367916/16490), by AD [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4122/16490), theorem 0.3 of lecture 17 of [these MIT lecture notes](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-125-measure-and-integration-fall-2003/lecture-notes/18125_lec17.pdf) by Jeff Viaclovsky, or the proof of the general version by uforoboa [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/66038/16490), which I attempt to repeat [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2584477/16490).

But there is such a nice duality between the results. Do they not admit dual proofs? Let's write the theorems this way:

$$m\leq \mu \leq M$$

implies

$$m^{\frac{1}{p}-\frac{1}{q}} \leq \frac{\lVert f\rVert_p}{\lVert f\rVert_q}\leq M^{\frac{1}{p}-\frac{1}{q}}$$
with the left- (resp. right-) hand side of the inequality below holding when the left- (resp. right-) hand side of the inequality above hold.

I thought to use the concave version of Jensen's inequality with power $q/p$, but it yields the same bounded above inequality. Is there is a notion of a dual $\sigma$-algebra on $X$ exchanging $\varnothing$ and $X$, for which bounded below measures become bounded above?

Comment: Here is an easy (read: non-messy) proof for the second assertion (in case $p \ge 1$): First show $\|f\|_\infty \le m^{-1/p} \, \|f\|_p$. This can easily done by contradiction. The general version follows by interpolation.